# boost.regex:switching between ascii and unicode

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, utf-8

Is there a convenient way in boost.regex to switch between ascii and utf?

The only way I see right now is to, for example, switch between `boost::u32regex` to `boost::regex`.

Is this the only way to switch between unicode and ascii? 

I was hoping to be able to just pass a parameter to boost, specifying my character encoding, thus-by not have to duplicate a lot of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the only way to switch between unicode and ascii?

Pretty much. What you think of as [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/basic_regex.html) is really a type alias:

```
namespace boost{
    template <class charT, class traits = regex_traits<charT>  >
    class basic_regex;

    typedef basic_regex<char>      regex;
    typedef basic_regex<wchar_t>   wregex;
}
```

Note that the character type is a template parameter - it's not a runtime parameter. Since `boost::regex` is built on `char`, it cannot support unicode.

[`boost::u32regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu/unicode_types.html) is the same way:

```
typedef basic_regex<UChar32,icu_regex_traits> u32regex;
```

In order to really generalize between them, you would have to write everything as a template too. Instead of taking a `boost::regex`, you take a `boost::basic_regex<charT, traits>`. That's one of the downsides of templates - they kind of just permeate everything.